# Why can I not use the font name listed in the fc-list's output?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue LT Pro 55 Roman} % This line is OK.
\setsansfont{HelveticaNeueLT Pro 55 Roman} % This line is ERROR!

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The MWE is above.

The xelatex complains with the following message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "HelveticaNeueLT Pro 55 Roman" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.4 \setsansfont{HelveticaNeueLT Pro 55 Roman}
                                               % This line is ERROR!
```

However, the fc-list outputs as follows:

```
/usr/share/fonts/adobe/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf: \
Helvetica Neue LT Pro,HelveticaNeueLT Pro 55 Roman: \
style=55 Roman,Regular
```

To my knowledge, `HelveticaNeueLT Pro 55 Roman` should be a correct font name, and `Helvetica Neue LT Pro 55 Roman` should be not. However, the actual result seems `Helvetica Neue LT Pro 55 Roman` is a valid font name and `HelveticaNeueLT Pro 55 Roman` is not. Why?

Is the fc-list's output reliable to give font names?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand; the first entry you get is `Helvetica Neue LT Pro`, so this seems to be the name you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `fc-list` output after the comma is, but XeTeX seems to want the family name (before the comma, `Helvetica Neue LT Pro`), optionally followed by the style (`55 Roman`). This gives the first line you used. So the fc-list output seems to be reliable, just not that part.

I don't have Helvetica Neue LT Pro, but I experimented with Latin Modern (which I guess most people with TeX installed has). `fc-list | grep 'LM Roman 10'` gives

```
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-bold.otf: Latin Modern Roman,LM Roman 10:style=10 Bold,Bold
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-bolditalic.otf: Latin Modern Roman,LM Roman 10:style=10 Bold Italic,Bold Italic
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf: Latin Modern Roman,LM Roman 10:style=10 Regular,Regular
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-italic.otf: Latin Modern Roman,LM Roman 10:style=10 Italic,Italic
```

Now for XeTeX we have

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % OK
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular} % OK
\setmainfont{LM Roman 10} % Not OK
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman 10 Italic} % OK, font is italic and \textit gives upright
```

---

LuaTeX on the other hand seems find fonts using the name after the comma, but not fonts where the style is specified (so I guess only the second line in your example would work with LuaTeX). However when accessing fonts this way it doesn't seem to find different styles.

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % OK
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular} % Not OK
\setmainfont{LM Roman 10} % OK, but \textit etc. doesn't work
\setmainfont{LM Roman 10 Regular} % OK, but \textit etc. doesn't work
\setmainfont[ItalicFont=LM Roman 10 Italic,...]{LM Roman 10} % OK
```